# How can we extract Outlook documents using Redemption.dll (version: 5.6.0.3644 )?

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am using the Redemption.dll (version: 5.6.0.3644). I want to use the ‘IRDODocumentItem’ to extract documents from Outlook folders. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I am not extracting attachment from the mail. I have a simple Folder in outlook that contains some word and excel documents. I did some research and extracted them like this

```
if (objItem is RDODocumentItem)
            {
                RDOAttachments rdoAttachments = null;
                RDOAttachment rdoAttachment = null;

                try
                {
                    rdoAttachments = ((RDODocumentItem)objItem).Attachments;
                    if (rdoAttachments.Count > 0)
                    {
                        RDOAttachment attachment = ((RDODocumentItem)objItem).Attachments[1];
                        attachment.SaveAsFile(path);
                        NAR(attachment);
                        rdoAttachment = rdoAttachments[1];
                        rdoAttachment.SaveAsFile(path);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    NAR(rdoAttachment);
                    NAR(rdoAttachments);
                }
            }
```

Is it the correct way to extract document ?